# Plotting a tree hierarchy using ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, hierarchy, ggraph

I have the following `tree` `hierarchy` `data.frame`:

```
hierarchy.df <- data.frame(raw=rep("Unclustered",26),
                           cluster.itr1="1.1,1.1,1.3,1.2,1.2,1.1,1.3,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.6,1.3,1.2,1.4,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.2,1.1,1.3,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.6,1.4,1.5",
                           cluster.itr2="2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,2.3,2.10,2.11,2.5,2.8,2.12,2.13,2.14,2.3,2.4,2.15,2.8,2.16,2.17,2.18",
                           cluster.itr3="3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,3.10,3.11,3.12,3.13,3.14,3.15,3.16,3.17,3.18,3.19,3.20,3.5,3.21,3.22,3.23,3.24,3.25",
                           cluster.itr3="4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8,4.9,4.10,4.11,4.12,4.13,4.14,4.15,4.16,4.17,4.18,4.19,4.20,4.21,4.22,4.23,4.24,4.25,4.26",
                           stringsAsFactors = F)
```

It describes an iterative clustering process where we start off with unclustered data (`hierarchy.df$Unclustered`), and in each iteration re-cluster each individual cluster from the previous iteration. Convergence is reach when no cluster can be broken down to finer clusters any more.

In this example convergence has been reached after 4 iterations.

I'm trying to plot this `hierarchy` using the `ggraph` package:

```
hierarchy.df$pathString <- do.call(paste,c(hierarchy.df,sep="/"))
hierarchy.graph <- data.tree::as.Node(hierarchy.df)
hierarchy.igraph <- data.tree::as.igraph.Node(hierarchy.graph)
igraph::V(hierarchy.igraph)$class <- names(igraph::V(hierarchy.igraph))

ggraph::ggraph(hierarchy.igraph,layout='tree')+
  ggraph::geom_edge_link(arrow=arrow(length=unit(3,'mm')),end_cap=ggraph::circle(1,'mm'))+
  ggraph::geom_node_label(aes(label=class))+theme_void()
```

which gives me:
[image]

So what's wrong here is that cluster 1.3 of iteration1 gets pointed upwards from the root rather than being leveled with all other clusters of that iteration and hence the tree looks bad.

Any idea how to fix this or to use another plotting package to do this in?

Comment: I think you may want to explicitly pass the root node, like `ggraph::ggraph(hierarchy.igraph,layout='tree', root = "Unclustered")`. But I can't test this properly, I get odd results when trying to run your example code (all the nodes at each level pasted/combined into a single node)

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Marius Maybe add your solution as an answer? Might help others in the future, and then we can close this question.

Answer (score 1):

In your example plot, it looks like the wrong node has been set as the root. You can pass additional arguments to the layout algorithm in your `ggraph()` call, allowing you to explicitly specify what the root node should be:

```
ggraph::ggraph(hierarchy.igraph,layout='tree', 
               root = "Unclustered")
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius. Would you happen to know how to color each clade (from the root) in a different color? I can post as a separate question if you think it deserves its own post.